# Resetting serial field annually in MS Access 2016

Tags: database, aggregate-functions, ms-access-2016

After digging the net for days with no luck, I hope to find the answer here.

I have a simple ms access 2016 database and I have a table with **Period** as one field and **Serial** as a second field.

**Period** is a number that represents a year.

I would like to make **Serial** a calculated field with the following formula:

```
Nz(DMax("[Serial]","[Table1]","[Period] = " & Year(Date())),0) + 1
```

I am trying to get a result similar to:

```
Period   | Serial
------------------
2016     |   1
2016     |   2
2016     |   3
2017     |   1
2017     |   2
2018     |   1
```

That is a serial number that should be reset every new year.

However, Access seems not to like **DMax** and it issues the following error message:

> The expression .... cannot be used in a calculated column.

Is there an acceptable way to make it?

Comment: Custom unique identifier is a common topic. Won't be able to do in a table Calculated type field. Here's how I do it to restart the sequence each year http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=23329

Comment: @June7: Thanks. You can put your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Not necessary, since I didn't do more than point to an example.